# js html backgroundColor vs highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i made a table in html and by using the fnRowCallback method and calling:
`datatableview.make_xeditable(xeditable_options)`
i added the following code to make an Unread row background color as yellow
under datatableview.js:

```
return function(nRow, mData, iDisplayIndex) {
        $('td a[data-xeditable]', nRow).editable(options);
        var html=String(mData[7]);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var a= (div.innerText);
        if (a=="Unread"){
            nRow.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
```

my problem now is when i press a row in my table if the row is not in yellow background (because it has "read") the row highlight works good but if the row is Unread, the highlight is not shown well

[image]
you can see in row 4 its ok and in row 6 the background is over the highlight 
my code on select in my index.html:

```
 table.on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
           if(e.ctrlKey ){
                $(this).toggleClass( 'selected ');
               console.log(table.$("tr.selected"))
           }
           else{
                table.$("tr.selected").removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

           }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.selected {
    background-color: blueish !important;
}
```

This will probably work.

Comment: This will be part of your `selected` css class